# Running command line: can't find file

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to run a few commands from VBScript:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\scripts"
objshell.Run "lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"
WScript.Sleep 500
wshshell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

But I get this error

> biarimport.vbs(4, 1) (null): The system cannot find the file specified.

It seems pretty obvious that either `lcm_cli.bat` or `LCMBiar_Import.property` file is not there but it's not the case it's all there and it works fine if I directly run it through CMD.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a statement

```
objShell.run "cmd /c C:\some\folder"
```

does not change the working directory to that folder. It just spawns a CMD instance, which throws an error that the command `C:\some\folder` isn't recognized and then closes immediately (`/c`).

Because the working directory didn't change, the subsequent statment runs in the wrong working directory and thus can't find `lcm_cli.bat`:

```
objshell.run "lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"
```

Either use the `CurrentDirectory` property for changing the working directory:

```
objShell.CurrentDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\scripts"
objshell.Run "lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"
```

or run the batch script with its full path:

```
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\scripts\lcm_cli.bat"" -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"
```

Note that any path containing spaces must be put in nested double quotes when used in a `Run` statement (bot not with the `CurrentDirectory` property). Also, you don't need `cmd /c` for starting batch scripts. It's only required if you use CMD built-ins like `dir` or I/O redirection.

Comment: Hi, I got what you are saying and clubbed my commands in one objShell.run "cmd /c cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\scripts & lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"

Comment: But this command "lcm_cli.bat -lcm..." requires me to hit an enter to proceed! Any idea how to do that

Comment: That is a different question, so please post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've asked this as a new question. Please answer that also.